# Concatenate pandas entries into a single column list

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_example = {'col1':['A', np.NaN, 'A', np.NaN, 'A'], 
    'col2':[np.NaN, 'B', 'A', np.NaN, 'A'], 'col3':['A', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'C', 'B'], 'col4':['D', np.NaN, 'B', 'D', 'A']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_example)
print(df)

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    A  NaN    A    D
1  NaN    B  NaN  NaN
2    A    A  NaN    B
3  NaN  NaN    C    D
4    A    A    B    A
```

I would like to create a dataframe column with a list of all columns in the rows which do not have NaN values, i.e. this

```
print(df['new_column'])

['col1', 'col3', 'col4']
['col2']
['col1', 'col2', 'col4']
['col3', 'col4']
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
Name: new, dtype: object
```

I have tried using the following function with `apply()` to create a column with all elements in a list.

```
def put_items_in_list(row):
    return [row['col1'], row['col2'], row['col3'], row['col4']]

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: put_items_in_list(row), axis=1)

print(df['new'])

0        [A, nan, A, D]
1    [nan, B, nan, nan]
2        [A, A, nan, B]
3      [nan, nan, C, D]
4          [A, A, B, A]
Name: new, dtype: object
```

However, with this lambda `apply()` function, I need to manually specify each of the column names.

Also, I would like to keep track of the column names of non-NaN row values, not the row values. In order to do this, there would be many if statements, which feels computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
>>> df['new_column'] = [
...     [df.columns[i] for i, item in enumerate(row) if item != 0] 
...     for row in df.fillna(0).values.tolist()
... ]
>>> print(df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4                new_column
0    A  NaN    A    D        [col1, col3, col4]
1  NaN    B  NaN  NaN                    [col2]
2    A    A  NaN    B        [col1, col2, col4]
3  NaN  NaN    C    D              [col3, col4]
4    A    A    B    A  [col1, col2, col3, col4]
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is very transparent as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can `stack` and  `groupby`:

```
df['new_col'] = df.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0').level_1.agg(list)
```

Or `apply`:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna().index), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
level_0
0          [col1, col3, col4]
1                      [col2]
2          [col1, col2, col4]
3                [col3, col4]
4    [col1, col2, col3, col4]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a bit confused by the first line, with `stack` and `groupby`. Could you comment a bit more what it does? I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'level_1'` on certain DataFrames.

Comment: @EB2127 you can run each step by itself, which is what I have done. For example, df1 = df.stack() stacks all of the columns on top of each other according to all non-NaN values in the dataframe. That creates two new columns which you then do a group by and aggregate the values to a list.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm having difficulty deciding which to mark as "right", so I thought I would give some points to the other posters. However, this is an excellent answer, and it was the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the columns and do an `np.where` to make all values that are not `np.NaN` equal to the header. Then, you can create a new column that `.join`s the other columns into a string and `.split`s them into a `list`.

```
for col in df.columns.to_list():
    df[col] = np.where(df[col].isna(), np.NaN, col)
df['new'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x).split(','), axis=1)
```